# Is it correct to state that 2 bars 4/4 drumloops is 8/4?

Tags: time-signatures

I've lots of drumloops recorded, that are (given the BPM at which they were recorded) long 4 beats per bar (i.e. 4/4), for 2 bars.

Here's opened in my DAW:

[image]

Is it correct to state that they are in fact 8/4 drumloops? The accent is every 8 quarters.

Comment: Which bit do you think represents the accent every 8 quarters?

Answer (score 5):

No, carry on stating that you have two bars of 4/4

If you tell someone you have one 8/4 bar, they'll be puzzled and you'll have to explain yourself anyway.

Comment: So which tempo is that?

Comment: I know I don't have "two bars of 4/4", else the "accent" will repeat after 1 bar. But in fact, it repeats after 8 beats...

Answer (score 2):

Late response here. 8/4 doesn't work like that. It's about the rhythm accent of the song. 8/4 could be expressed in 3 + 3 + 2 for example. There is a really good example of the difference between 4/4 and 8/4 in the song "into the light" by the band "2002". Most of the song is in 4/4 but the piano instrumental part feels like 8/4 if you count 4/4 it feels kind of weird and it's because the rhythm accent is like 3 + 3 + 2.

But the end of the day is somehow subjective because a musician could write the entire song in 4/4, it's just a matter of perception.

Answer (score 1):

In this case the wave form of bar 2 looks identical to the wave form of bar 1. The wave form is 2 bars long in 4/4 time and the second bar is the same as the first. The 4 quarter note subdivisions can be seen below the wave form.

This pattern looks like bass drum on 1 and 3& and snare drum on 2 and 4 with high hat (or cymbal) varying between 8th and 16th notes.

Phrases can be more than one bar long with no repetitions and accents can occur anywhere in a phrase. Neither of those determine the time signature.

Comment: They are not identical, they are similar. You hear the "repeat" after 8 beats...

Comment: @markzzz the rhythmic pattern is identical. If a drummer plays a 1 bar pattern there will be subtle differences from bar to bar. I stand by my answer, 4/4. You seem to resist the idea that this is 4/4. Your question even states “2 bars 4/4 drum loop”. Is there a reason you want this to be 8/4? Would you count this song off as 12345678?

Comment: @Belzaguy Yes I do. For almost every drumloops I think: 12345678. Song apart, because It can fit within a 4/4 Song...

Answer (score 0):

The way it sounds will be 8/4, so it's better written that way. The accent on the first beat of each bar makes it so. If it was 4/4, you'd need to signify that one bar is accented, and the next isn't.

Anyone reading 8/4 might think it a little odd, but the time sig. needs to reflect what actually happens. All music should be written in the easiest way to read and make sense.

Fact - two bars of 4/4 are two bars of 4/4. If that 'compartment' of music translates to ***one*** bar, it can be called 8/4. It's *not* an improper fraction. Some music has way more than 8 crotchets per bar.

Comment: One of these days, a dver is going to explain! Don't mind dv, but on its own, it's meaningless to all except the dver. Come on, get realistic.

Comment: not sure if you are ironic or are you talking seriously?

Comment: @markzzz - about what in particular? Answer or comment? No irony here. All serious.

Comment: what is a dver?

Comment: @markzzz - a dver is a shortened version for one who downvotes (dv). We can more often than not understand an upvote, looking at the quality of what's been upvoted. Sadly, not so with a dv.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can speculate about the dver's reasoning: Drum patterns can be longer than 1 bar, and they need not accent every downbeat.  If the OP says there's an accent every 8 beats, that sounds to me like it's a 2 bar pattern in 4/4.

Comment: "that sounds to me like it's a 2 bar pattern in 4/4", thus, 8/4? :P That's the question... you "feel" the repeat after 8 beats, not 4. That's why they are not for me 2 bars of 4/4: it will repeat after 4 beats in that case, isn't?

Comment: @markzzz - where did you get the quote from? I don't understand. I'm agreeing with you.

Comment: @Tim from ibonyun above, he written that comment

Comment: @markzzz - when you want to address a particular person with a comment, use '@xxxx'. I guess the comment wasn't to me.

Comment: @Tim it wasn't. I was talking with ibonyun

Answer (score 0):

If you and everyone working on this piece of music agrees that they hear 8/4, then the music is in 8/4. You can write it down in 8/4 and count it in 8/4.
If someone were to transcribe the drum loop(by itself) by ear, they would likely notate it in 4/4. It is normal for a drum loop to last more than 1 bar.